# Using Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I'm setting up Facebook auth into my app. I'm testing the login flow right now, and after successfully calling Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('public_profile,email') the user returned doesn't have the scope information, only id and token inside authData.facebook.

Look at FacebookUtils this is expected - but then I'm wondering what is the recommended way to query for the user information (email, name, etc) once the user is authenticated? I would have expected this info to be included in the response and included in the user created by Parse.

When a user authenticates with Facebook for the first time, we still redirect them to our signup form to get more data. Information that can be retrieved from Facebook is prefilled.
Because of this, I'd like to make use of the user.existed() function to know if it's a new Facebook user or not and decide if we redirect them to signup or not.

When I do

```
const user = Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn()

if (user.existed()) {
  if (Parse.FacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
```

user.existed() seems to always be true. I've made sure to clear all my cookies, delete the users created in my parse dashboard (and the Session), but I always get true here.
So not sure what I'm doing wrong here. (Are there more stuff I should delete in my parse dashboard?).

The second one I'm confused about is isLinked.
In the case of an user already existing, I understand isLinked is used to linked 2 accounts. This case is interesting for us, because we'd like to allow users to signup with their email and later on be able to login with Facebook.
This function also seems to always return true. How is it looking for a non-linked user through this?

The last thing that confuses me, is that when the facebook user is created by the Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn() process, it is created with no information from facebook, except the facebookId and user_token.
This confuses me about why FacebookUtils is even a thing (no offence).

Right now I am using FB.api('/me' ... to retrieve the user info after the facebook login and then check is the user returned by FacebookUtils.logIn() has an email, in which case it tells me that it is an existing user, else that it's a new account.

I'm obviously hacking it right now because I can't figure how to properly use isLinked/existed/etc.

Some guidance would be great, thanks :)

Comment: did you find a solution? we are experiencing the exact same issue...

Comment: @AlbertoDallaporta sorry for not answering sooner. No did not get any answer. The Parse support community seems to be slowly dying and honestly most answers I've had haven't been very welcoming. We're planning to move away from Parse.

Comment: Yeah the docs are horrible for `Parse.Util.Facebook`, moving away from Parse also.